# Does Wordpress work with MySQL active-active GTID-Based Replication without any issues?

Tags: mysql

Does WordPress work with MySQL active-active GTID-Based Replication without any issues?

Is it suitable for the production WordPress website?

I would like to set up the same with WordPress 6.2.2 and MySQL 8.0.34. However, I'm unable to find solid proof that it will work without any issues on the production website.

The plan is two web servers with WordPress as the backends of a HTTPS LB and two MySQL servers (active-active GTID based replication) as backends of a TCP LB.

User --> Load Balancer (Web call) --> web-vm-1 OR web-vm-2 --> Load Balancer(DB connection) --> mysql-master-vm1 OR mysql-master-vm2

Comment: Are you asking this for a factual answer or are you asking this for opinions/discussions? You need to phrase your questions so that a single clear factual answer can be marked as the _correct_ answer, if you're looking for a discussion/opinions then this isn't an appropriate place. Right now it's not clear from your question which you're wanting. Otherwise I'm unsure how this is different from the linked stackoverflow question?

Comment: Thanks, Tom. Updated my question.